# Python: Repeated Syntax error (Minecraft MCP setup)

Tags: python-3.x, minecraft

I am trying to decompile the minecraft bin folder for modding right now and have run into this error multiple times and I have looked around and couldn't find a way to fix it.

The Error: 
[image: The error]

The files referenced in the picture are [here](http://db.tt/ITqpiusn) and [here](http://db.tt/NX65OR5S).

I have Python 3.2.3 installed so I don't know why it says Python 2.6.

Thanks for any help in advance!

--ZD9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script uses Python 2 and requires, as we can see, Python 2.6+, while you have Python 2.5 or older installed.
Python 3 doesn't count here.